# Hibernate Firing Update query on an entity even when there is no property changed

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have spring boot project with JPA hibernate. The setup is very common - RestController - Service - Repository.
There is one particular endpoint with Return type of Entity. The service fetches the entity from db, does some calculation and returns it to the client. The problem is, as soon as the service call returns, an update query is fired on this entity in the back end. None of the entity property is changed. Repository.save() also is not called still update query is being fired. I want to understand this behavior and possibly stop it.

If fetch is all i am doing, I don't want the JPA/Hibernate to fire an update query if save() or saveAndFlush() is not called. its resulting unnecessary load on db.

Comment: Post your codes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An entity returned from the database is "managed" in the world of hibernate. So when the transaction block / boundaries close hibernate may issue a save back to the db because it thinks that the entity is dirty and needs to be updated with the in memory / hibernate cache info it has.

I do not think that you can skip this as is part of how hibernate works. Even if you see an update being issued I suggest you do not worry.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced such problem. The idea of hibernate that it considers some type of values as 'dirty', and every time you try to get data via transaction Hibernate tries to define which data is changes, but it doesn't work with some kind of data (like @Lob), and hibernate defines it like changed by default. Hence one of decision of this issue is detaching entity from Hibernate context via EntityManager. But you have to know: since you are detaching entity from context you will face LazyInitException if your boundings inside entity are  fetch = FetchType.LAZY

```
@NonNull
@Transactional
public List<YourEntity> find(@NonNull FindListPojo flp){
    return repository.find(flp)
            .stream()
            //due to service above current is using transaction and hibernate thinks that @Lob
            //is always 'dirty', every time while calling this method
            //tries to update unchanged entity in DB, hence we have to detach
            //entities to avoid redundant updating in the DB
            .peek(entityManager::detach)
            //risk of LazyInitException while obtaining Lazy data inside entity!
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```